# pip install PIL already, but still face ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Tags: bash, python, pip

I'm trying to `pip install Pillow` , and did install it, but still shows ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

```
jetson@jetson-desktop:~/Desktop/test_12.26$ sudo pip install Pillow
The directory '/home/jetson/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/jetson/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

jetson@jetson-desktop:~/Desktop/test_12.26$ python3 12_26_img_to_text.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "12_26_img_to_text.py", line 12, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

my python version, in Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

```
jetson@jetson-desktop:~/Desktop/test_12.26$ python --version
Python 2.7.17
jetson@jetson-desktop:~/Desktop/test_12.26$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
```

---

- update status
    `Failed building wheel for Pillow`,

after I used `pip3 install Pillow`, and also `sudo pip3 install Pillow`failed

the error message

```
jetson@jetson-desktop:~/Desktop/test_12.26$ pip3 install Pillow

Collecting Pillow
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/2a/2fc11b54e2742db06297f7fa7f420a0e3069fdcf0e4b57dfec33f0b08622/Pillow-8.4.0.tar.gz (49.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 49.4MB 13kB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: Pillow
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Pillow ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-eyaxo3bq/Pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmphzj_avj9pip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  /usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
  running egg_info
  writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.c'
  warning: no files found matching '*.h'
  warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
  writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  
  
  The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
  
  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-build-eyaxo3bq/Pillow/setup.py", line 1024, in <module>
      zip_safe=not (debug_build() or PLATFORM_MINGW),
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 204, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 78, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-eyaxo3bq/Pillow/setup.py", line 790, in build_extensions
      raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-eyaxo3bq/Pillow/setup.py", line 1037, in <module>
      raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
  
  The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
  
  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
  
  
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for Pillow
  Running setup.py clean for Pillow
Failed to build Pillow
Installing collected packages: Pillow
  Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-eyaxo3bq/Pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-o9s5i0si-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    /usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
    writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    
    
    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-build-eyaxo3bq/Pillow/setup.py", line 1024, in <module>
        zip_safe=not (debug_build() or PLATFORM_MINGW),
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 589, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 78, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-eyaxo3bq/Pillow/setup.py", line 790, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-eyaxo3bq/Pillow/setup.py", line 1037, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
    
    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    
    
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-eyaxo3bq/Pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-o9s5i0si-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-eyaxo3bq/Pillow/
```

Comment: You mention `pip install` which loads the requested package for the *default* python; which is python2 on 18.04; yet don't mention installing it for `python3` where you'll actually use it?

Comment: I'm using python3 most of the time, such as `python3 my_script.py`, and what shall I do for this?

Comment: To install additional packages for python3 you use `pip3 install` ; `pip install` installs additional packages for the *default* python which was python2 in 18.04.

Comment: oh, I understand ur logic, thanks so much!! I will try that

Answer (score 1):

after I upgrade pip3 with `pip3 install --upgrade pip`

that `pip3 install Pillow` is working